# Creating a email service in node.js

Tags: node.js, email, mern, nodemailer

I am trying to create email scheduling service for the user in a MERN stack application.
I am using nodemailer for the emailing service. But I requires enabling "access to less secured apps" in google account settings. The users will not feel safe with that option.

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: userEmail,
        pass: userPassword
    }
});
```

This is the code. It requires client id, secret and access token for nodemailer to send mail without "allow to less secure apps enabled". But I don't think I can get that info.
Is there any other way to solve this or any alternative?

Comment: Why can't you get a client id, secret and access token?

Comment: I was getting user gmail id and password from the frontend. I am not sure how to get client id and secret. Please share if you know any way to find out that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know when but google updated their security against unauthorized way of sending mail. As of now we are in developing phase so we comes under that category.

Method 1:-
You can use app password feature provided by google. Just go on your google profile and in security section you will have the option of app password, there you just have to create a password for your password which will be temporarily activated for developing purposes.

Method 2:-
You can use a third party which will do this for you. Currently I am using "mailtrap" for this work you can also do this by following the given instructions or you can check by yourself on the official website.

`const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

```
const sendEmail = async (options) => {
    var transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io",
        port: 2525,
        auth: {
            user: "b970e161dc43e5",
            pass: "8ca678877af03a"
        }
    });

    const mailOptions = {
        from: process.env.SMTP_EMAIL,
        to: options.email,
        subject: options.subject,
        body: options.body
    }

    await transport.sendMail(mailOptions);
}

module.exports = sendEmail;`
```